# Python regular expression match number in string

Tags: python, regex

I used regular expression in python2.7 to match the number in a string but I can't match a single number in my expression, here are my code

```
import re
import cv2

s = '858  1790 -156.25 2'
re_matchData = re.compile(r'\-?\d{1,10}\.?\d{1,10}')
data = re.findall(re_matchData, s)
print data
```

and then print:

```
['858', '1790', '-156.25']
```

but when I change expression from

```
re_matchData = re.compile(r'\-?\d{1,10}\.?\d{1,10}')
```

to

```
re_matchData = re.compile(r'\-?\d{0,10}\.?\d{1,10}')
```

then print:

```
['858', '1790', '-156.25', '2']
```

is there any confuses between d{1, 10} and d{0,10} ?
If I did wrong, how to correct it ?
Thanks for checking my question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`r'\-?\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{1,10})?'`

use `(?:)?` to make fractional part optional.

for `r'\-?\d{0,10}\.?\d{1,10}'`, it is `\.?\d{1,10}` who matched `2`.

Comment: Thanks for checking my question, I ignored that the last part was an optional part  in my expression

Answer (score 1):

The first `\d{1,10}` matches from 1 to 10 digits, and the second `\d{1,10}` also matches from 1 to 10 digits. In order for them both to match, you need at least 2 digits in your number, with an optional `.` between them.

You should make the entire fraction optional, not just the `.`.

```
r'\-?\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{1,10})?'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed that '.' have such useful feature in regular expression when I wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do as follows:

```
import re
s = '858  1790 -156.25 2'
re_matchData = re.compile(r'\-?\d{1,10}\.?\d{0,10}')
data = re_matchData.findall(s)
print data
```

Output:

```
['858', '1790', '-156.25', '2']
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I thought this style was a little be like a trick and not easy to read